# How to give different port for Apache and Nginx in 10.10?

Tags: apache2, nginx

I am curios to know how can we assign different port to **Apache** and **Nginx** in 10.10.

I installed nginx first then apache, so when I start my machine, `nginx` is taking default port: `80`.

I have to manually close `nginx` server and start `apache` server.

Is there any we can assign different port to them so they will start on different port and will not collide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit /etc/apache2/ports.conf with root permission and change Listen value

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

[image]

change 80 to 8010, restart apache2 server. Now Your server's url(address) will be

```
http://localhost:8010
```